# blank screen before splashscreen for ionic3 application

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

i am getting a blank screen before splash screen in android. i tried solution 
  given in   stackoverflow but those were creating issues. here is my code.
 if i use styles.xml theme then it says theme is not compatiable
       styles.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/screen</item>
   </style>
 </resources>
```

AndroidManifest

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="8" 
   android:versionName="0.0.8" package="com.app.ngoAdmin" 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" 
  android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" 
  android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" 
   android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity 
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" 
   android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" 
   android:name="MainActivity" 
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" 
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/multi_app_name" 
    android:name="com.synconset.MultiImageChooserActivity" 
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </activity>
    <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" 
    android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" 
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
  </application>
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line on config.xml file if already added please replace it.

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="800" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
```

now build the android app using `ionic cordova build android --prod` and check it your black screen issues is resolve make sure when run the app please don't forgot --prod option

Answer (score 0):

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Use this in your app theme as per your Requirements

Comment: giving following error ===>
  
  
  
  
  
..\platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:37: AAPT: error:
'@android:styles/AppTheme' is incompatible with attribute android:theme (attr) reference.

Comment: please share your app base theme from styles and compile sdk version also share manifest also if possible

Comment: If you are experiencing issues while using AAPT2, you can disable it by setting android.enableAapt2=false in your gradle.properties file

Comment: I will share it. Right now not on desk.